# Why this is a bad bubble sort algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I started studying *Data Structures and algorithms,* and tried to implement Bubble sort:

```
def BubbleSort(list):
    for a in range(len(list)): 
      for b in range(len(list)):# I could start this loop from 1
        if list[a]< list[b]:   # to avoid comparing the first element twice
          temp=list[a]
          list[a]=list[b]
          list[b]=temp
    return list
```

I browsed the net and books - but found no Python implementation of bubble sort.
What's wrong with the above?

Comment: What do you mean with "there is no such implementation"? It is bad in the sense that it will sort the list in the opposite way, and that it will take approx 2 times the amount of time necessary, and that it is not bubblesort.

Comment: I meant no such implementation for bubble sort, but as you just say it's not bubble sort.

Comment: `I browsed the net` speed reading? Have a look at [Q&A@CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=python%20bubble%20sort).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. the algorihm will not always sort correctly;
2. syntactically it seems to sort the opposite way;
3. it takes twice the amount of time necessary to perform bubble sort;
4. it is *not* bubblesort; and
5. you better never use variables in Python named `list`, `dict`, etc.

*BubbeSort* sorts by comparing two **adjacent** elements: the so-called "bubble". If checks if the left item is indeed less than the right one. If this is not the case, it swaps the elements. The algorithm iterates maximum *n* times over the list, after which it is guaranteed to be sorted.

So a very basic implementation would be:

```
def BubbleSort(data):
    for _ in range(len(data)):  # iterate n times
        for i in range(len(data)-1):  # i is the left index of the bubble
            if data[i+1] > data[i]:  # if the left item is greater
                # perform a swap
                temp = data[i]
                data[i] = data[i+1]
                data[i+1] = temp
    return data
```

Now we can improve the algorithm (approximately let the algorithm work in half the time) by stopping at `len(data)-1-j`, since after each iteration, the right most element over which the bubble has moved is guaranteed to be the maximum:

```
def BubbleSort(data):
    for j in range(len(data)):  # iterate n times
        for i in range(len(data)-1-j):  # i is the left index of the bubble
            if data[i+1] > data[i]:  # if the left item is greater
                # perform a swap
                temp = data[i]
                data[i] = data[i+1]
                data[i+1] = temp
    return data
```

But using bubblesort is - except for some very rare cases - inefficient. It is better to use faster algorithms like *QuickSort*, *MergeSort*, and *TimSort* (the builtin sorting algorithm of Python).

Comment: (I'd make that 1) there's *one* `bubble sort [algorithm]` 2) The code presented does *not* implement it.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short list of books which implement `bubble sort:`

1. [Fundamentals of Python: Data Structures, 1st ed.: Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GJTRCZM)
2. [Introduction to Numerical Programming: A Practical Guide for Scientists and Engineers Using Python and C/C++ (Series in Computational Physics)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466569670)
3. [Fundamentals of Python: First Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1111822700)
4. [Python 3 for Absolute Beginners (Expert's Voice in Open Source)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216328)
5. [Python Data Structures and Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786467356)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the for loop from index a + 1 instead of 0 which will avoid comparing the first element to itself. Makes it a bit faster.

Use the swap function to swap the values of the list[a] and list[b] elements, rather than using a temporary variable.

Use the sorted function to check if the list is already sorted, and return the list immediately if it is.